# Subir múltiples archivos con PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy tratando de subir múltiples archivos PDF al servidor con un ciclo `for`, este es mi codigo

**HTML**

```
<input type="file name="acta_baja" value="<?php echo $acta_baja; ?>" multiple="">                            
<span class="error">* <?php echo $acta_bajaErr; ?></span>
```

**PHP**

```
         if (!empty($_FILES["acta_baja"]["name"])) {
            $num_files = count($_FILES['acta_baja']['tmp_name']);
            $permitidos = array("application/pdf");     
            $limite_kb = 1000000;

            for($i=0; $i < $num_files;$i++){

              if(in_array($_FILES["acta_baja"]["type"][$i], $permitidos) && $_FILES["acta_baja"]["size"][$i] <= $limite_kb * 1024){
                $ruta = '../../files/actas_baja/enfriadores/'.$idnext_solicitud.'/';
               if(!file_exists($ruta)){
                mkdir($ruta);
               }    
               $ruta2 = '../../files/actas_baja/enfriadores/'.$idnext_solicitud.'/'.$idnext_enfriador.'/';
               if(!file_exists($ruta2)){
                 mkdir($ruta2);
               }
               $acta_baja = $ruta2.$_FILES["acta_baja"]["name"][$i];
               if(!file_exists($acta_baja)){
                  $resultado1 = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["acta_baja"]["tmp_name"][$i], $acta_baja);

                } else{
                  $acta_bajaErr= "El archivo ya existe";
                }
              } else{
                $acta_bajaErr= "Formato no valido o el archivo sobrepasa el tamaño permitido.";
              }
            }  
          }else{
              $acta_bajaErr= "El acta de baja es obligatoria";
          }
```

El problema es que al enviar los datos me envía `$acta_bajaErr = "Formato no valido o el archivo..."` no se está validando correctamente el `if` de permitidos, y no está subiendo los archivos, gracias de antemano

Comment: en realidad para subir múltiples archivos , el name del input debe ser así `name="nombre[]"` , debes representarlo como array.

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez era ese pequeño detalle, olvide prepararlo como arreglo, gracias